# Scraping files behind href=# by feeding the web page with dates

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xhtml, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the following page: https://rapor.pmum.gov.tr/rapor/xhtml/ptfSmfListeleme.xhtml

What I need essentially is to feed the web page dates I need (above the table) and then download the data for these days in a form of excel file available at the bottom of the page.

The thing is I do not know how i can adjust the dates in the easiest way. Mechanize is an option, but i use Python 3 so it is unavailable. Also the link to excel file is href=# and is downloaded automatically. How do I access and store it somewhere?

Here is my code for scraping:

```
import requests
import numpy as np
from lxml import html


payload = {'//*[@id="PmumBI:baslangicTarih_input"]': '23.06.2015', '//*[@id="PmumBI:bitisTarih_input"]': ['23.06.2015'],'//*[@id="PmumBI:j_idt35"]':['submit']} 
page = requests.post("https://rapor.pmum.gov.tr/rapor/xhtml/ptfSmfListeleme.xhtml", data=payload) 
#page = get('https://rapor.pmum.gov.tr/rapor/xhtml/iskkRapor.xhtml',proxies=dict(c.pyxos‌​.proxies)) 
tree = html.fromstring(page.text) 
data=tree.xpath('//td[@role="gridcell"]/text()') 
data=np.array(data)
```

Comment: Do you have some code that you have tried?

Comment: `payload = {'//*[@id="PmumBI:baslangicTarih_input"]': '23.06.2015', '//*[@id="PmumBI:bitisTarih_input"]': ['23.06.2015'],'//*[@id="PmumBI:j_idt35"]':['submit']}
page = requests.post("https://rapor.pmum.gov.tr/rapor/xhtml/ptfSmfListeleme.xhtml", data=payload)
#page = get('https://rapor.pmum.gov.tr/rapor/xhtml/iskkRapor.xhtml',proxies=dict(c.pyxos.proxies))
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
data=tree.xpath('//td[@role="gridcell"]/text()')
data=np.array(data)
` this however is for just scraping whatever is on a page when dates are changed. however, they do not change.

Comment: i am sorry for the low readability of the comments I am still new here and try to figure it all out.